# Ignoring C function declaration in comments

Tags: python, c, function, declaration, analysis

I have a task to analyze declaration of functions in c in python.
My regex finds all functions but it finds also declarations that are commented which is wrong like example:

```
unsigned    int  *hashfn(const char *str, ...);
//unsigned int *hash_function(const char *str, unsigned int htab_size);
```

I need to ignore second function.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your regex? Furthermore I would suggest you use a (C-)parser that does the analysis for you. This will be more correct and will offer you more convenience.

Comment: re.findall(r"\w[\w\s\.\*]*\([\[\]\w\s\.,\*]*\)\s*[;\{]", content)

Comment: Does your regex also incorrectly find a function in a string literal like "unsigned    int  *hashfn(const char *str, ...);"?

Comment: And how about forms such as `/*`<br/>`unsigned int foo(void);`<br/>`*/`, or `#if 0`<br/>`unsigned int foo(void);`<br/>`#endif`?

Comment: Yes it finds functions in string too but it wrong too and yes wouldnt find function in /*...*/ comments but it does